# Is there a way to confirm a user's employer during an online log-in?

Tags: api, authentication

Does anyone know of *any* solution for checking that a user is still employed by the company who pays for their access to my web app?  The problem I'm trying to address is that my client's admin users aren't great at killing the accounts of users who no longer work for that company.

It would be ideal if there were some generic way of asking a company's HR system "Does employee 0001 still work for you?"

Currently working with a very small user base, so acquiring more info on users (e.g. employee reference number etc.) is relatively easy.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to reliably check for this.  However, that's not the problem, your approach is.  Give the company an incentive to validate the accounts.  Either charge a fixed fee on top of any usage charges so that dormant accounts cost them money, or make the accounts go dormant after a short period of time such as a month so that the client is forced to revalidate periodically.